# Can't solve red Underline in woocommerce cart page title

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't find any reason why there is a red underline under the payment details. i am using wordpress and woocommerce for my project. can't get any css for that underline. pls give me any suggestion. 
I am using "Zerif Lite" wordpress theme.
[red underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Uo5.png)
[working website](https://8foldlanguage.com/payment/)
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The red underline is basically just a pseudo element. You can overwrite it with the following selector: .woocommerce-page .page-title::before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pseudo selector **:before** used for class **page-title** which is coming from woocommerce styles

```
.woocommerce-page .page-title:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #e96656;
    content: "";
}
```

Which has the

> background: #e96656;

Comment: yes. Ajaj  with someone's suggestion I already solve this problem. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The title has a before element defined with css. If you want to remove the red line you can set the background-color transparent with '.woocommerce-page .page-title:before'.

[image: Red line]

Comment: Thanks a lot. works like a magic. I was just looking for underline or border. Never think off background can solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks again  for your quick help Joris

Answer (score 0):

```
.woocommerce-page .page-title:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #e96656;
    content: "";
}
```

by using this class ".woocommerce-page .page-title:before" you  can modify your own css properties.